# How to Stop Hybris server from command prompt or Admin console

Tags: java, e-commerce, server, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to add a new extension and for that I need to stop hybris server first, but I am unable to figure out how exactly I should STOP the server: through command line or by admin Console?
I cannot type any command as my server is running.
I also started the server by using hybrisserver.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command /bin/platform/hybrisserver.sh stop

That will stop the server.

Comment: when I am running the server from "/bin/platform/hybrisserver.sh" and then I try to stop it using your solution an error occurs : The hybris Server 5.1.0.0 service is not installed

Answer (score 5):

just push ctrl + c in the command line window and the server is shut down properly

Comment: Will this stop only the latest batch process or all executed previously ?

Answer (score 2):

As a small side note, if you'd like to stop a hybris server through the admin console, you could always go to **Console > Scripting Languages > Edit Statement** and execute `System.exit(0);`

hybris has got all the necessary runtime shutdown hooks to do a graceful (as if you did `CTRL + C`).

In theory it's also possible to restart the hybris system internally by executing:

```
import de.hybris.platform.core.Registry;
Registry.destroyAndForceStartup();
```

By default, there's a restriction to forbid doing so using groovy scripts, though.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happen that the hybrisserver is runned on another console and even after `hybrisserrver.sh stop` some processes are still running. And you will receive message like:

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already
```

My solution is (for linux based systems):

```
lsof | grep hybris
```

To get the processes runned from "hybris" directory(change on you need) and then kill the listed processes with:

```
kill -15 <PROCESS_ID>
```

PS. (This solution require the root privileges)